# What do I need to learn to write a program that will send data to a preprogrammed microcontroller through USB?

Tags: usb, transfer, data-transfer

Understanding that my programming experience only stretches back a few months, i'm unsure how to phrase this question, but bear with me. I'm open to any criticism and will gladly update my question with whatever details you ask for, but anyways.... My question is, is there a certain API that I should look into, or a certain compiler I should use to create a program that would send a few bytes over a usb link to a micro-controller on the other end? How would the program identify which port to sent the information to? Thanks. I'd be glad to rephrase this question if need be.

Comment: You want an api for sending some data over usb? On which Operating System?

Answer (score 2):

It might be substantially easier to just use a USB-to-serial converter; sending a few bytes over a USB serial port is going to be a lot easier on both ends. Devices like the [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) or the [TI MSP430 launchpad](https://estore.ti.com/MSP-EXP430G2-MSP430-LaunchPad-Value-Line-Development-kit-P2031.aspx) (for a whopping $4.30) have USB-to-serial devices onboard so it's almost transparent, and reading the incoming data and sending back data is going to be almost *stupid* easy and there will be a *boatload* of tutorials on how to do it for the inexperienced, like [this one for the Arduino](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lesson4.html).

Comment: And if all you need is to send some data to the device just use Hyperterminal (or equivalent).  I've used that technique in almost every case I need to send data to the device.  Only when I wrote a custom bootloader did I need to actually write custom code to send data out the port, but if you use the FTDI USB-Serial converter chip then it's like talking to a serial port.  No brainer.

Answer (score 0):

There's [pyusb](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyusb/index.php?title=Main_Page), which is portable and written in Python, an easy language to pick up. It's a wrapper around [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/), a C library. There are also Perl and Lua and Java and Ruby (etc.) wrappers for it.